# What is this called and where can I buy a replacement?

Tags: prusa-i3, extruder, anet-a8, repair

In the image, [image]there is an object circled in blue on the anet a8 printer that I need to buy a replacement of, however, I can not find it online, please help.

Answer (score 5):

This is the throat block for direct drive extrusion, Anet8 is a cheap clone of Prusa printers, so it's easy to find parts for Anet printers.

This is one extruder kit that may help your needs, [1 Unidades Impresora 3D makerbot MK8 Extrusora De extrusión de Aluminio Bloque de DIY Kit para Reprap i3](https://es.aliexpress.com/store/product/1Set-3D-Printer-makerbot-MK8-Extruder-Aluminum-extrusion-Frame-Block-DIY-Kit-for-Reprap-i3/1962255_32715673423.html?spm=a219c.search0104.3.269.W5yIqd&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10345_10342_10343_10173_10340_10341_10541_10562_10084_10083_10307_10060_10155_5680016_10154_10056_10055_10539_10537_10312_10059_10313_10314_10534_10533_100031_10103_10073_10102_10557_10142_10107,searchweb201603_25,ppcSwitch_5&btsid=79693e48-00b7-4029-908d-314b37935569&algo_expid=64c2aa2b-e9de-4722-8ecb-0ba5542f5a86-34&algo_pvid=64c2aa2b-e9de-4722-8ecb-0ba5542f5a86). This is a link for Aliexpress - of course there are other dealers.

Comment: Note that "throat" is Chinglish for "heatbreak".

Comment: @TomvanderZanden That could be because the Chinese do not know whether to use *heat break* or *heat brake*. Neither do I.

Answer (score 3):

This is part of [filament drive](http://3dprinting-blog.com/tag/3d-printer-upgrade/). Anets do not sell it separately, only as a part of extruder assembly, but other manufacturers may make incompatible parts: of different size (not fitting into bracket), filament channel position, etc.

Answer (score -3):

Like @ZuOverture said the name of this component is the filament drive. Most of the manufactures sell the whole extrusion device already assembled, to avoid mismatches between the components of the extrusion device. If your device is somehow damaged, and without possibilities to be used in the printer the easiest solution would be to buy a new extrusion device. If financially is unfeasible for you, you may have the option to generate the 3D model of this piece and share the file to someone who could print this component for you.

Comment: I don't think this is a printable component. It looks like it needs to be made of metal, because the heatbreak screws into it. Plastic would melt.

Comment: Can you check the material? For my 3D printer, most of the filament drive is made of ABS. The heating system on the extruder is made of Alu and brass. In the photo you have showed it looks like that is just a component to give support and stability, the heating system is below near to the extruder. I have a question for you, what is the problem with your component? You have said that you need a replacement , but did not explain why... Did you brake it during the assembling of your printer? Or did arrived to you already broken? What is the problem?

Comment: I agree with @TomvanderZanden. It needs to be made of metal since it is acting as a heat sink as part of the cold end.

Comment: Hello @Mick, could be made of metal yes. Anyway, Tom could easily check which material is made the component. And still, the important question is what happened with the original piece. If it is made of metal is difficult to damage, maybe is possible to reuse it. And most likely he will need to buy the whole extrusion device as a replacement for the piece. I am curios to know what has happened to this component. Cheers!